# Could Cannabidiol steady a hand?

Tags: human-biology, biochemistry, neuroscience, medicine, surgery

Can Cannabidiol be used to steady shaky or nervous hand for precision work like surgery?

I have used it for shooting pool/billiards and I'm not sure if it is a placebo or it is helping? but I am more steady.

I have seen where Cannabidiol helps this man with Parkinson's stop shacking.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rAdDdTZuNA8

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a question of applied medicine. The question would be on-topic on [Health.SE](health.stackexchange.com).

Comment: I'm also voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a question of applied medicine. Please Migrate The question would be on-topic on Health(health.stackexchange.com).

Comment: surely you should migrate it rather than close it?

Comment: This question is self-help and in its current state it cannot be migrated to Health.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is a fantastic question.

As far as the Parkinson's application, it's definitely within the realm of possible. Taken form a recent review:

> Preclinical research in animal models of several movement disorders
>   have shown variable evidence for symptomatic benefits but more
>   consistently suggest potential neuroprotective effects in several
>   animal models of Parkinson’s (PD) and Huntington’s disease (HD).
>   Clinical observations and clinical trials of cannabinoid-based
>   therapies suggests a possible benefit of cannabinoids for tics and
>   probably no benefit for tremor in multiple sclerosis or dyskinesias or
>   motor symptoms in PD.

Kluger et al. in Movement Disorder, 2015 (The Therapeutic Potential of Cannabinoids for Movement
Disorders)

As far as every-day hand steadiness, I haven't been able to find any good sources yet. I'll keep reading, and update this if I find anything interesting.